# Using Old version of a framework x inside a pod y while using latest version of framework x for main project

Tags: cocoapods

I have a local pod that has to use an older version of the OpenSSL framework. My main project uses this local pod and a newer version of the OpenSSL framework. This creates ambiguous use inside code. My question is if it is possible to make this older version reachable only from my local pod, but not from other pods or the main project file?

Answer (score 0):

Only by renaming all of the symbols in one of them. See https://github.com/google/boringssl for an example of this.

Comment: What happens if I want to import both new OpenSSL and my framework that uses the old OpenSSL in the same swift file? Will I get "ambiguous use of <var>" error?